# declared function ($.fn) is not a function

Tags: jquery, function, lottie

I am trying to let a lottie animation start, when in view. I declared a function

```
$.fn.isOnScreen = function(){

var win = $(window);

var viewport = {
    top : win.scrollTop(),
    left : win.scrollLeft()
};
viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

var bounds = this.offset();
bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));
};
```

and then call it

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
        if (jQuery('#circle-anim').isOnScreen()) {
           
           var circle = lottie.loadAnimation({
            container: document.getElementById("anim-badge-1"),
            renderer: "svg",
            loop: true,
            autoplay: true,
            path: "PATH TO JSON" // the path to the animation json 
});
  
        circle.playSegments(
  [
    [0, 30],
    [162, 575]
  ],
  true
);


        var anim;

        anim = lottie.loadAnimation(circle);
           
            alert("in viewport!");
        } else {
            console.log('not visible');
        }
    });
});
```

as soon as I scroll I get

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).isOnScreen is not a function at
> (index):102    at dispatch
> (jquery-3.5.1.min.dc5e7f18c8.js?site=60ec2441446e3d0b9389fa3c:2)    at
> v.handle
> (jquery-3.5.1.min.dc5e7f18c8.js?site=60ec2441446e3d0b9389fa3c:2)

any ideas why **isOnScreen** is not working?

Comment: It's working fine for me, what order do you run the scripts in? because the error states it has not been loaded, so are you sure it's loaded correct? Check your console for errors

Comment: this is an inline script, as I am working with webflow.